# Solving logarithm problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If $x=\frac{e^y-e^{-y}}{e^y+e^{-y}}$ show that, $y=\frac{1}{2}\log_{e}\frac{1+x}{1-x}$

What I've tried,

taking log to the base e on both sides, we get;

$\log_{e}{x}$=$\log_{e}{m^2-1}/m^{2}+1$, where $m=e^y$.

But, how should I proceed from here. Any further help or hint is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure about the $b$ on $$y=\frac{1}{2}\log_{e} {\color{red}{b}}\frac{1+x}{1-x}$$

Comment: You will find a proof under the name "transformation of tanh (hyperbolic tangent) into argtanh" (or inverse $tanh$ or $tanh^{-1}$)

Comment: That $b$ should *be one* in order for this to hold.

Comment: I am really really sorry. 'b' is not there in the original question. Please pardon me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from $$x=\frac{e^{2y}-1}{e^{2y}+1}$$ we get by multiplication with $e^{2y}+1$
$$e^{2y}+1=\frac{e^{2y}}{x}-\frac{1}{x}$$ from here we get
$$e^{2y}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)=-1-\frac{1}{x}$$ for $$x\ne 1$$ we get
$$e^{2y}=\frac{x+1}{1-x}$$
can you proceed?

Answer (score 3):

HINt: find $e^{2y}$ from $x=\dfrac{e^y-e^{-y}}{e^y+e^{-y}}$
$$x=\frac{e^y-e^{-y}}{e^y+e^{-y}} =\frac{e^y-e^{-y}}{e^y+e^{-y}}\times  \dfrac{e^y}{e^y} \\\to 
x=\dfrac{e^{2y}-1}{e^{2y}+1}$$then 
$$xe^{2y}+x=e^{2y}-1 \\e^{2y}(x-1)=-1-x\\\to e^{2y}=\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}$$now apply $\log$

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: @Abhishekstudent :can you go on ?

Answer (score 1):

*HINT:* Clear the denominator, distribute $x$, combine terms with $e^y$ and $e^{-y}$, then you can solve for $e^{2y}$. At this point, you can take natural logarithms.

Answer (score 1):

$$x = \dfrac{e^y - e^{-y}}{e^y + e^{-y}} \\ \implies x = \dfrac{e^{2y}-1}{e^{2y}+1} \quad\text{[Simplify it by multiplying something common both on top and bottom]} \\ \implies e^{2y} = \dfrac{1+x}{1-x} \text{more simplification} \\$$
There you have it

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{e^y-e^{-y}}{e^y+e^{-y}}=\frac{e^{2y}-1}{e^{2y}+1}=x$$

so that by inversion*

$$e^{2y}=\frac{1+x}{1-x}.$$

---

*when $x\ne1$,
$$\frac{z-1}{z+1}=x\iff z-1=zx+x\iff z(1-x)=1+x.$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all: we have that $e^y, e^{-y} > 0$, hence $e^{y} - e^{-y} < e^{y} + e^{-y}$, which shows that $x < 1$. Moreover, we have that $(-1)(e^{y} + e^{-y}) = -e^{y} - e^{-y} < e^{y} - e^{-y}$, so we have that $-1 < x$. We conclude that $x \in ]-1,1[$. This piece is needed in order to be able to do all transformations in the following solution.

Suppose $x = \frac{e^y - e^{-y}}{e^y + e^{-y}}$, then we have that
$$x(e^y + e^{-y}) = e^y - e^{-y}$$
and grouping the $e^y$ on the right hand side and the $e^{-y}$ on the left side, we find that 
$$(x - 1)e^y = -(x + 1)e^{-y}.$$
Therefore, we have that (swithching $e^{-y}$ to the right hand side) and the $x -1$ to the left hand side (which is possible since $x \neq 1$):
$$e^{2y} = \frac{1 + x}{1 - x}.$$
Taking the natural logarithm of both sides (which we can, since $\frac{1 + x}{1 - x} > 0$ because $x \in ]-1,1[$), we find
$$2y = \log_e\frac{1+x}{1 - x}.$$